# IntelliJ, disable automatic closing angle bracket on generics

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, if I type this:

```
ArrayList<MyType>(
```

I get this:

```
ArrayList<MyType>(>(
```

because IntelliJ is being too clever and automatically putting in the closing angle bracket and opening round bracket.  I find easier to type what I'm thinking than to right arrow, tab whatever to get past it.

It catches me every time and I'd love to be able to turn this off, but can't find the option.

Comment: [Insert pair bracket](http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/6388/20130314053120.png) controls all of these, including `(` and `<`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I have that turned off.  Still does it.

Comment: Try with [12.1 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP).

Answer (score 1):

It's broken in IntelliJ 11.5, fixed in 12.0+.